# AES-256 encryption/decryption

Tags: openssl, cryptography, aes

I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm struggling to understand what!

I **encrypt** a dummy string online on this website with AES-256:

https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

with the following parameters:

- text to encrypt: **This is a test!**
- Mode: CBC
- Key size in bit: 256
- Enter IV: 0000000000000000
- Secret Key: 3B1C2DDAA872F28A4CDCB3324394569B

the output (Base64 format) is:

**g+rR+egh2MCHFnYe0XJM7g==**

when I try to **decrypt** it from command line with openssl:

```
echo g+rR+egh2MCHFnYe0XJM7g== | openssl enc -aes256 -d  -out secret.dec -K 3B1C2DDAA872F28A4CDCB3324394569B -iv 0
```

I get this error:

```
bad decrypt
4780398188:error:06FFF06D:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong final block length:Sources/libressl/libressl-22.240.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:524:
```

Comment: These kind of online tools are commonly really badly written. For instance, an AES key should consist of random bytes. There is no way you can enter e.g. unprintable characters, so the "key" you enter isn't fully random. Basically you're teaching yourself bad crypto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert Key and IV to HEX.

```
echo g+rR+egh2MCHFnYe0XJM7g== | openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -out deco.dec -p -K 3342314332444441413837324632384134434443423333323433393435363942  -iv 30303030303030303030303030303030
```

OpenSSL expects the Key and IV in HEX. When you provide Key as **3B1C2DDAA872F28A4CDCB3324394569B** , it is padded with addtional zeros to make it

> "3B1C2DDAA872F28A4CDCB3324394569B00000000000000000000000000000000".

Similarly IV is converted to

> "00000000000000000000000000000000".

Hence OpenSSL ends up using wrong key and IV and decryption fails even though you provided the correct ones.

Note : Pass flag "-p" and openSSL will show what Key and IV are used.

Comment: this is great! thanks. How did you convert the Key to HEX?

Comment: figured that out ... any ascii to hex does the job :)

Comment: A follow-up question :) ... why do I need to convert this 3B1C2DDAA872F28A4CDCB3324394569B toHEX? it is already a hex value, right?